# Integrating $\sqrt{z}$ over different circles

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I'm doing a first exercise on complex integration where I have to calculate $\int_{\gamma}\sqrt{z}\ dz$ over $\gamma=C(2,1)^+,C(1,1)^+,C(0,1)^+$, where $\sqrt{z}=\exp(\frac12\mathrm{Log}(z))$ is the principal branch of the complex square root (so the integrals in question are well-defined). For $\int_{C(2,1)^+}\sqrt{z}\ dz$ I think I can apply Cauchy's theorem to directly conclude this integral equals $0$, for $\sqrt{z}$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}-(-\infty,0]\supset\overline{C(1,1)}$. For $\int_{C(0,1)^+}\sqrt{z}\ dz$, I did the following calculations, but am in doubt whether these are correct (do we need $\sqrt{z}$ to be holomorphic in an open set containing the domain of integration?):

$$\int_{C(0,1)^+}\sqrt{z}\ dz=\int_0^{2\pi}\exp(\frac12\mathrm{Log}(e^{ir}))ie^{ir}\,dr=\left[\frac23e^{\frac32ir}\right]_0^{2\pi}=-\frac43.$$

For $\int_{C(1,1)^+}\sqrt{z}\ dz$ either the substituion $r\mapsto1+e^{ir}$ or Cauchy's theorem does not seem to help me. Note: I only learned about the weak version of Cauchy's theorem, yet.

Question: Are my calculations for $\int_{C(0,1)^+}\sqrt{z}\ dz$ and$\int_{C(2,1)^+}\sqrt{z}\ dz$ correct? How should I approach $\int_{C(1,1)^+}\sqrt{z}\ dz$?

EDIT: I now have $$\int_{C(1,1)^+}\sqrt{z}\ dz=\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{e^{ir}+1}ie^{ir}\,dr=\left[\frac23(e^{ir}+1)^{\frac32}\right]_0^{2\pi}=0,$$ is this correct?

EDIT 2: Would it make more sense to use $(-\pi,\pi)$ as integration domain, since we are using the principal branch of the complex square root, which is defined as $\exp(\frac12\mathrm{Log})$, for the principal branch of the complex logarithm has image $\{z\in\mathbb{C}:-\pi<\mathrm{Im}\,z<\pi\}$?

Comment: The integral over $C(0, 1)$ is not correct. Remove a small part of the circle around its leftmost point. Then consider what the limits of the principal value of $z^{3/2}$ are when you approach $z = 0$ (for $C(1, 1)$) from above/below and when you approach $z = -1$ (for $C(0, 1)$) from above/below.

Comment: @Maxim thank you for your answer. Should the outcome then be $-4i/3$, and the outcome of the integral over $C(1,1)^+$ be $0$?

Comment: Yes, both are correct.

Comment: @Maxim okay, thanks for your verification!